# Migrating really old RedHat server to cloud

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, redhat, azure, cloud

I've got a client with a really, really, really old PHP3 webapp that runs on an ancient consumer-grade PC with RedHat 7.somethingOld. I've got backups of the software and database but he's very tight with his money and has been extremely resistant to upgrading just about any part of the system. Now he wants to close his physical office and go virtual. I'm looking for some advice on how to move this into something like Azure or AWS. I assume that RH that old isn't supported by any cloud hosting service.

As far as I can see my options are:

- compile PHP 3 or 4 for a more modern version of Linux that would be supported by the cloud. I've attempted this once some time ago and got lost in the maze of dependencies. If I recall correctly some were incompatible with each other.
- make a VHD copy of the old system and then setup a virtual server
  that would run the virtual copy. Sounds a little Inception to me,
  even if it would work
- tell him it's the end of the line and the software is too old to make this work and he needs to make the changes to the PHP code to
  make it run in a modern version
- run

Any thoughts?

Comment: Bring the code current, or run like hell. The other options are just too risky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update the code.  Running an application based on old PHP can pose a security risk for your customer.

Comment: And by "old" in this case we mean "hasn't seen a patch in fifteen years".

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to migrate a very old Red Hat server running PHP 5.1.x (more than 8 years old) to Azure using Centos 5.11 (latest I could use without breaking the application). The only way is through VHD uploading.

Main problems are:

- If you can't install the Azure Linux Agent, don't even continue, because you won't be able to even put the VM online.
- You won't have any kind of support by Microsoft and probably neither by third-party vendors. Forget inventory management, anti-virus, monitoring tools, etc.
- No matter how good you tighten the infrastructure security, your application server and code will have thousands of obvious holes.

In the end, you will be responsible for any problem that comes along, even if it's not related to infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare still supports quite old versions of RedHat. You might be able to P2V the current server, test it locally, then upload to vCloud Air.

You can then approach virtualisation as one task, and upgrades as a separate task.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat paradoxically, such extremely old application are somewhat *less* prone to security breakdown - simply because they are so old nobody is scanning/running with the relative exploits.

Surely the best solution is to upgrade your customer's application to run on newer PHP framework, but if it is not possible, your only solution is to load the entire virtual disk and run it as a standalone, fully virtualized guest.

VMWare, KVM and Virtualbox all works quite well even with very old guest, but I'm not so sure about the cloud providers. You really had to ask them if such an old guest can run.

Anyway, forget any kind of official support.